# Substitute of sys_refcursor in bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

In bigquery I have a requirement of passing multiple column values of multiple rows as single output parameter in procedure. In PLSQL it could be done by sys_refcursor.Is there any wayout in bigquery. Using below not return values for multiple rows.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE `linear-charmer-344806.2143.Test1`(v_name STRING, OUT v_dept STRING,out v_id numeric)
begin 
set (v_dept,v_id) =(select as struct dept,roll from `linear-charmer-344806.2143.Employee` 
where name = v_name);
end;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should not have issues running such query. You just have to be careful with the data type of the parameters you are passing and the name which you label the variables. About the cursors, I think on BigQuery you can use alternatives to it like using [loops](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/scripting#loops) which can offer some similar working behaviour.

To replicate your case I perform the following:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE `projectid.dataset.table`(
   fullVisitorId STRING,
   type STRING,
   visitId INT64
)

insert into `projectid.dataset.table`(fullVisitorId,type,visitId)values("4460792451076786377","PAGE",1496345687);
insert into `projectid.dataset.table`(fullVisitorId,type,visitId)values("8359479821939482641","PAGE",1496356529);
insert into `projectid.dataset.table`(fullVisitorId,type,visitId)values("9410889263646527987","WEB",1496357061);
insert into `projectid.dataset.table`(fullVisitorId,type,visitId)values("8801528329001387919","WEB",1496336519);
```

Create a procedure

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE `projectid.dataset.proc_test`(v_visitorid STRING, OUT v_type STRING,OUT v_id numeric)
begin  
set (v_type,v_id) =(select as struct type,visitId from `projectid.dataset.table`
where fullVisitorId = v_visitorid);  
end;
```

Calling the procedure this way will fill variables `type` and `id` with the result.

```
DECLARE type STRING; 
DECLARE id numeric; 
call `projectid.dataset.proc_test`("4460792451076786377",type,id);
select type,id;
```

Below, I'm looping, by using a `for` scripting statement, trough the values of a `table` that retrieves the `fullVisitorId`and use it later on to perform the call to the procedure.

```
DECLARE seekerid STRING; 
DECLARE out_type STRING; 
DECLARE out_id numeric; 

FOR record IN
  (SELECT fullVisitorId from `projectid.dataset.table`)
DO 
  SET seekerid = record.fullVisitorId;
  call `projectid.dataset.proc_test`(seekerid,out_type,out_id);
  select out_type,out_id;
END FOR;
```

**UPDATE 23/03/2022:** Below is a sample on how to create a procedure with an array struct variables as inputs. Please take note that you have to verify if the table and variables fit your inputs and data structure.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE `projectid.dataset.proc_test_struct`(v_inputs ARRAY<STRUCT<type STRING,visitId INT64>>, OUT v_fullVisitorId STRING)
begin  
declare v_struct STRUCT<type STRING,visitId INT64>; 
set v_struct = (select (type,visitId) from unnest(v_inputs));
set v_fullVisitorId = (select fullVisitorId from `projectid.dataset.table` where type = v_struct.type and visitId = v_struct.visitId);
end;
```

Here is the part where I'm calling the procedure and filling it with a `struct` variable.

```
declare v_inputs ARRAY<STRUCT<type STRING,visitId INT64>>; 
declare v_fullVisitorId STRING;

set v_inputs = [("PAGE", 1496356529)];
call `projectid.dataset.proc_test_struct`(v_inputs,v_fullVisitorId);
select v_fullVisitorId;
```

I consult the official documentation so if you want to dig further you can check the following links:

- [Scripting Statements](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/scripting)
- [Writing a Procedure](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/scripting-concepts#writing_a_procedure)
- [SET](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/scripting#set)
- [FOR](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/scripting#for-in)
- [STRUCT](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-types#struct_type)
- [DATA TYPES](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-types)

Comment: How can I pass array of struct as input parameter? Something like: CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE `projectid.dataset.proc_test`(v_visitor  ARRAY<struct<type string, visitId int64>>,
OUT v_id numeric)
begin  
--your code
end;--------- when I am calling the procedure with CALL `projectid.dataset.proc_test`(("PAGE",1496345687), id); I am getting error

Comment: I have updated my answer please take a look. That will fill the scope of the question. Please if you have more questions unrelated to the original question, I suggest you to open a new question.

Comment: Also, I suggest to check the documentation about `datatypes` about arrays and structs as it have some limitations on bigquery.

Comment: sorry but it didnt work. I tried in another way like CALL  proc `((select ARRAY<STRUCT<roll numeric, dept STRING>>[(1,'ECE'),(2,'ECE')] ), id);
select id;

Comment: did you manage to get it working then? I updated the question and tested on my side and it worked. nevertheless, I'm glad that you manage to get it working on your side.

Comment: Yes thanks for your help. Obviously they helped me to get an idea atleast.